# How to include shortcodes into php email template

Tags: php

I have confirmation email that is sent after user registers. Now, I want admin to be able to customize this email, change content. etc (don't want to hardcode it)

But problem here is with activation link that I would generate. I figured that I could save email content in database. The problem is with dynamic elements that I MUST add to email, like activation link, site name, etc.

Whats the best way to go with this, I suppose I would add so called 'shortcodes' like wordpress does. Whats the blueprint for this and how to integrate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve it by using a simple template system based on search & replace; I've included a very basic one below with a short example. Hope it helps you :)

```
class EmailTemplate
{
        private $body;

        public function __construct($template)
        {
                $this->body = $template;
        }

        public function render($context)
        {
                return preg_replace_callback('/%{(.*?)}%/', function($v) use ($context) {
                        return isset($context[$v[1]]) ? $context[$v[1]] : '';
                }, $this->body);
        }
}

$tpl = new EmailTemplate(<<<EOM
Hello %{user}%,

How are you doing. This is your link:

%{link}%

See ya!

EOM
);

echo $tpl->render(array(
        'user' => 'world',
        'link' => 'http://www.php.net/',
));
```

Comment: VERY nice, thanks you :)