# Php, pull place holders out of a variable

Tags: php

I have a variable that contains "place holders" that should be replaced with db info once ran. This is for making generic emails.

Here is an example of the variable:

```
$emailBody = "Dear [-first_name-] [-last_name-]";
```

I then will call the db for first_name & last_name and replace those placeholders with the appropriate values.

Now my end goal is to find those key terms and turn them into:

```
$emailBody = "Dear John Smith";
```

So I guess I need a way to explode the value into an array looking for [- -] then do the fix then make $emailBody equal to the modified variable. I'm just having a hard time figuring out how to look for each set of [- -].

Comment: I don't always extract and replace place holders from a string, but when I do I prefer `preg_replace_callback()`

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
$emailBody = "Dear [-first_name-] [-last_name-]";

$tokens = array("[-first_name-]", "[-last_name-]");
$replacements = array("John", "Doe");
$emailBody = str_replace($tokens, $replacements, $emailBody);
```

Comment: Don't run a loop. str_replace will operate on an array as long as the match and replacement arrays line up.  http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#example-4697

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [str_replace function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$emailBody = 'Dear [-first_name-] [-last_name-]';

$search = array('[-first_name-]', '[-last_name-]');
$replace = array('John', 'Smith');

$emailBody = str_replace($search, $replace, $emailBody);
```

Will leave $emailBody as "Dear John Smith"

Answer (score 0):

This is how I typically handle mail merge. It uses a regular expression to find all strings enclosed by `[-` and `-]` and then performs a replacement on the matches it can find.

The difference with `str_replace()` or `strtr()` solutions is that it allows you to find *any* pattern that satisfies `[-xxx-]`, not just the ones you expect. You can handle that condition however you like:

```
$user = new stdClass; // this may well be an array
$user->first_name = 'Jack';
$user->last_name = 'Jackson';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\[-([a-z_]*)-\]/', function($match) use ($user) {
    $field = $match[1];
    if (isset($user->$field)) {
        return $user->$field;
    }
    // the field was not present, decide what to do
    return ''; // or: return $match[0];
}, $emailBody);
```

See also: [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback)

---

Similar answers I've given before:

[How to include shortcodes into php email template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251200/how-to-include-shortcodes-into-php-email-template/12251312#12251312)

[Fastest way to replace string patterns by mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438240/fastest-way-to-replace-string-patterns-by-mask/14438832#14438832)